# How to get the following inequality by Taylor's formula.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, boundary-value-problem

I am stuck at the proof of the following lemma:

Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded domain. Let $\partial D$ be of class $C^2$. Let $\nu$ be the outward normal vector on boundary. Then there exists a positive constant $L$ such that 
$$
|\nu(x)\cdot\{x-y\}|\leq L|x-y|^2
$$
for all $x,y\in\partial D$.

Proof: Let $\Gamma =\{x(s):s\in[0,s_0]\}$ be a regular parameterization of a patch $\Gamma\subset \partial D$ with $x'(s)\neq0$ for all $s$. Then by Taylor's formula we have

\begin{aligned}|v(x(t)) \cdot\{x(t)-x(\tau)\}| & \leq \frac{1}{2} \max _{0 \leq s \leq s_{0}}\left|x^{\prime \prime}(s)\right||t-\tau|^{2} \\|v(x(t))-v(x(\tau))| & \leq \max _{0 \leq s \leq s_{0}}\left|\frac{d}{d s} v(x(s))\right||t-\tau| \\| x(t)-x(\tau) | & \geq \min _{0 \leq s \leq s_{0}}\left|x^{\prime}(s)\right||t-\tau| \end{aligned}

The proof is completed then.

My question is how to get the first inequality by Taylor's formua?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in this kind of proofs one actually assume $x'(\tau)=0$ (which is possible up to taking a rotation of the domain $D$). Therefore one simply have the Taylor expansion (up to taking multi indices in the higher dimensional case)

$x(t)=x(\tau)+x'(\tau)(x-\tau)+\frac{1}{2}x''(\zeta_t)(t-\tau)^2$ for some $\zeta_t\in [0,s_0]$

and hence $x(t)-x(\tau)=\frac{x''(\zeta_t)}{2}(t-\tau)^2$. Therefore the first inequality is just Cauchy Schwarz (recall that the norm of the normal vector is just one) plus the above equality, taking the sup on all possible $\zeta_t$, killing the dependance in $t$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But why we can choose $x'(\tau)=0$ here? Since now $x'(s)\neq0$ by assumption.

Comment: You are very welcome. I do not see how you can get rid of $x’$ term if not.. Where did you take this theorem from?

Comment: I find this in the book of Rainer Kress, "Linear integral equation", Lemma 6.16.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that what I said to you is wrong: my answer works if you thinks of $\Gamma$ as the graph of a $C^2$ function. If I have a new answer, I’ll write to you